# How to create a button with a loading animation using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?

Tags: html, forms, button, input, label

"Hi, I'm working on a project and I'm trying to create a button with a loading animation that displays while an action is being performed, such as submitting a form or loading content. I'm not sure how to approach this, could you provide some guidance or code examples on how to create a loading button using JavaScript?"

to receive guidance or code examples on how to create a button that displays a loading animation while an action is being performed, such as submitting a form or loading content.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is not working as expected? To make it easy, When would the loading animation need to start? When would it end?

Answer (score -2):

In JS you would need a something like

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myButtons .btn").click(function(){
        $(this).button('loading').delay(1000).queue(function(){
            $(this).button('reset');
            $(this).dequeue();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

the #myButtons is where you would input your div id for your buttons(if theres no div then just your button id)

for html you would need to have a

```
//Div for button(s) goes here
<form action="#" autocomplete="off">
//button(s) go here
</form>
//end div here
```

this should work it worked for me.
What this does is after you click your button the text will go from the text you have for you button(lets say 'Submit'), it would turn into "Loading..."

the .delay(1000) is in milliseconds I believe

now I know this isnt what you want to do, but try to implement(with the code I gave you to actually have the loading button)  a document.readyState. I want you to try first, before I give you the answer as it will make it easier for you to remember

I hope this helps)

Comment: this is not how it works. And this is not really a test of this case. A loading animation must be triggered instantly if you try to POST and must end on a RESPONSE. It is an asynchronous issue not an issue with a delay. You can't possibly know that RESPONSE resolved after exactly 1 second. It could be sooner or later. Last but not least, if you POST a form with a submit you would by default be redirected... making all animations that are Jclient-sided obsolete as they wouldn't appear anymore.

Comment: yeah I am aware that its asynchronous issue, it has nothing to do with a delay, but if you think about it as "loading new page" type of way, you would obviously put more time on the loading button until the new page loads by however long you want it to load for. If it is for new page. But, I have updated my answer to include document.readyState if its for pulling a document. I wont go over how it works as OP most likely didn't know it existed(hence his answer), but In my opinion you can learn faster if you figure things out. And even then, you seem to know so help explain aswell man